# How to prevent organic group administrator to add users without acceptance from user

Tags: organic-groups

When a non-member subscribes to a Drupal organic group, the subscribsion state goes normally to "waiting" and "accepted" after group admin accepts. How to keep the same flow when group admin adds users to his own group, so that the user could accept or reject the subscribtion. Now when the group admin adds users to his group, they are automatically added without asking permission from the user. I have tried to change the group permissions etc. but can't figure out how to make this flow work also for this direction.

Comment: Are you using rules? You can set og status I believe if you get the conditions correct.